# Vuex store and access to Vue.prototype

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm starting work with Vue. I tried find solution in another posts but without success. So:

I have 2 parts of code:

```
//main.js
...
    const axiosInstance = axios.create({
        mode: 'no-cors',
        baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
    })
    
    Vue.prototype.$http = axiosInstance
    Vue.config.productionTip = false
    
    new Vue({
      router,
      store,
      vuetify,
      i18n,
      render: h => h(App),
    }).$mount('#app')
```

and

```
//store.js
export default new Vuex.Store({
...
    actions: {
      [AUTH_REQUEST]: ({commit, dispatch}, user) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          commit(AUTH_REQUEST)
          this.$http.post('/auth/login', user)
            .then(resp => {...}
        })
    }
})
```

when I trigger `this.$store.dispatch(AUTH_REQUEST, ...)` in component method, I see error in console, like as `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '$http' of undefined`.
I tried by `this.$http`, by `this._vm.$http` - the same.

Comment: vuex actions don't have a value for `this`

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that attaching the `axiosInstance` to `Vue.prototype` makes it available only in subsequent child vue components and not the store.

To access `axiosInstance` from the store, you will need to import it.
A way could be to refactor the axios instance to its own file and include the file in main.js so it is executed.
Then in the newly created axios file, export `axiosInstance` so it can be imported by the store file.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can reach this instance only in vue js components. You need wrap axios another js file after that you have to import to vuex file. Im using like that it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers. I made like this

```
//utils/axiosHelper.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';
import router from '@/router';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  // withCredentials: true,
  mode: 'no-cors',
  baseURL: 'correctUrl',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    // 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  },
})

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    if (!config.url.includes('auth')) {
      if (localStorage.getItem('user-token') !== null) {
        config.headers['Authorization'] = localStorage.getItem('user-token')
      }
    }
    return config;
  })

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  resp => {
    return resp
  }, error => {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      router.push('/auth/login');
      localStorage.setItem('isAdmin', null);
      localStorage.setItem('user-token', null);
    } else if (error.response.status >= 400) {
      console.log(error.response.data);
      alert(error.response.data.error);
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  })

Vue.prototype.$http = axiosInstance;

export default Vue.prototype.$http;
```

and then

```
//store.js
...
import $http from '@/utils/axiosHelper'
...
export default new Vuex.Store({
  ...
  actions: {
    [AUTH_REQUEST]: ({commit, dispatch}, user) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        commit(AUTH_REQUEST)
        this.$http.post('/auth/login', user)
          .then(resp => {...})
      })
    },
  ...
})
```

and then

```
//main.js
...
import $http from "@/utils/axiosHelper"
...
Vue.use($http)
```

and still I see `Cannot read property '$http' of undefined` when I try trigger `AUTH_REQUEST`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you should move your Axios instantiation code to its own file.

File: `app/src/libs/axios.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'

// axios
import axios from 'axios'
import updateToken from '@/auth/middleware/updateToken'

const axiosIns = axios.create({
  // You can add your headers here
  // ================================
  // baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  // timeout: 1000,
  // headers: { 'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar' },
})

// Or you can use an interceptor if adding tokens etc.
// ======================================
axiosIns.interceptors.request.use(async config => {
  const token = await updateToken()
  config.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
  return config
})

Vue.prototype.$http = axiosIns

export default axiosIns
```

File: `app/src/store/index.js`

```
...
import axiosIns from '@/libs/axios'

axiosIns.get('/some/url').then(data => { console.log(data) })
...
```